# Can't index arrays in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

I've been trying to learn some assembly and was testing out arrays and found that when I tried to print out the value at the point indexed nothing happened, after experimenting further it appears that even though I am using the arrays as shown in many examples across the internet, it just simply isn't working

Here's the code:

```
section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov eax, num ; eax now contains 5
    mov ebx, [array+8] ; ebx now contains 8
    cmp eax, ebx ; compares eax to ebx
    jge skip ; should not happen because eax is smaller than ebx
    call printdigit
skip:
    call printn
    call _exit

printdigit:
    mov eax, 0x30
    add [num], eax
    mov ecx, num
    mov edx, 1 ;length
    mov ebx, 1 ;write to stdout
    mov eax, 4 ;write call number
    int 0x80
    ret

printn:
    mov eax, 0x0A
    push eax
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, esp
    mov edx, 1
    int 0x80
    add esp, 4
    ret

_exit:
    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 0
    int 0x80


section .data
    num dw 5
    array dw 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

The commands I'm using to compile the code

```
nasm -f elf Bubblesort.asm
ld -m elf_i386 -s -o Bubblesort Bubblesort.o
./Bubblesort
```

What I'm running:

ubuntu 22.04.3 desktop amd64, (on virtual machine but shouldn't matter I think)

The output I want should be

```
5
```

The actual output

I want printdigit to be called **only** when num is less than whatever is indexed at array

I am almost certain its not a computer issue but a code issue but I'm unsure where

I have now done the following changes

```
_start:
   mov eax, [num]
   mov ebx, [array+8]
   cmp eax, ebx
   jae skip
```

```
section .data
    num dd 5
    array dd 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

the rest of the code is as normal

this now prints the value i want when array is indexed to a value greater than num, but when it isn't greater it still prints the value

Comment: Your data is words but you use them as dwords, which one would you prefer?

Comment: @harold Would this cause an issue, I dont really mind dwords probably

Comment: Then change `dw` to `dd` to use dwords

Comment: @harold this does not fortunately fix the issue at hand, but thank you for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov eax, [num]
    movzx ebx, word [array+12]
    cmp eax, ebx
    jb skip
    call printdigit
    jmp exit
skip:
    call printn
exit:
    call _exit

printdigit:
    mov eax, 0x30
    add [num], eax
    mov ecx, num
    mov edx, 1 ;length
    mov ebx, 1 ;write to stdout
    mov eax, 4 ;write call number
    int 0x80
    ret

printn:
    mov eax, 0x0a
    push eax
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, esp
    mov edx, 1
    int 0x80
    add esp, 4
    ret

_exit:
    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 0
    int 0x80


section .data
    num dd 3
    array dw 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

`mov eax, num`

eax = address of num, my debugger shows value 00402000.

`mov ebx, [array+8]`

ebx = 00050004.

`cmp eax,ebx`

eax >= ebx so code jumps to `skip` label.

Write function prints `0x0A` which is `new line` code. If You change to `0x35` You will see `5`.

`printdigit` code is never executed.

Comment: Apologies, it appears I didn't clarify, I was trying to get it so that the jump doesn't happen, my thought with this code is that should be comparing the value of num with array indexed at 8 which should be 5 and 8. The comparison does not happen as i wish it to, i want it not to skip. also how are you getting the values of the registers, what debugger is this?

Comment: I just tested this with `jb` instead of `jge` and code prints `5` + newline.

Comment: Ahh, so do these values count as unsigned? and how do i tell?

Comment: Yes, because most significant bits are equal to 0 in array values and num.

Comment: also apologies this does print out the value but i want it not to do this when num is less than array at whatever index chosen

Comment: Whether the numbers are unsigned is up to you, as signed number they would be positive anyway so it makes no difference. That doesn't make them unsigned though. if you want to load the value of num instead of its address then you need `mov eax, [num]`.

Comment: it now prints a value but when i change the index of the array to a value that has a lower number

Comment: I attached code. If `num` is less than value in `array` nothing will appear on the screen.

Comment: It does not do that for me, maybe it is not a code issue? are you using exactly what im using?

Comment: sorry i didnt noticed you changed the code in your answer i will look at that

Comment: thank you your code has made me realise my error thank you very much I've been stuck on this for a while, but i realise the code examples have been doing byte arrays therefore my indexing was wrong in the first place along with multiple other things